# SQL Server stops whenever i try to connect in ssms

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, mdf

Here is my ERRORLOG

```
2022-04-07 14:59:40.31 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -d C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
     -e C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
     -l C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
2022-04-07 14:59:40.31 Server      Command Line Startup Parameters:
     -s "MSSQLSERVER"
2022-04-07 14:59:43.93 Server      Error: 17113, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2022-04-07 14:59:43.93 Server      Error 32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.) occurred while opening file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf' to obtain configuration information at startup. An invalid startup option might have caused the error. Verify your startup options, and correct or remove them if necessary.
2022-04-07 14:59:43.93 Server      SQL Server shutdown has been initiated
```

Comment: That doesn't look like SSMS has anything to do with it. It looks like the `master` database that the instance is trying to use is open by *something* else; perhaps another instance (I hope not), or you've (for some reason) opened the file in some kind of editor.

Comment: Also make sure that your anti-virus software has folder exclusions setup for `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA` and `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log`.